# What is the meaning of the icons in and the letters below the train drawing on a UK train announcement board?

Tags: uk, trains, national-rail

At this train announcement board, there are two lines near the bottom.  One with a drawing of a train, below that letters.  The letters refer to coach numbers, so this does not tell me where on the platform I need to be, like announcements in other countries do.  Some of information was blinking.

The drawing appears to tell me where to put my bicycle and where the coffee place is, but what do the symbols otherwise mean, and why are some letters filled and others not?

[image: train announcement]

Comment: It looks to be displaying how full each carriage is ?

Comment: Presumably it's showing what percentage of the seats are reserved in the carriage, rather than the live occupancy level.

Comment: Yep reservation levels https://www.virgintrains.co.uk/about/media-room#/pressreleases/virgin-trains-helps-passengers-during-the-christmas-rush-1279269

Answer (score 15):

I'm not 100% positive but here is what I think it means.

- The letters are the Coach Letters.
- Letters in inverted type are first class coaches, those in normal type are standard class coaches.
- The cup and bycycle indicate the location of the onboard shop and the cycle storage (Coaches C and A)
- The end that is chamfered to look like a driving cab is the front of the train (furthest from the concourse at Euston).
- The amount of fill on the coach pictures indicates roughly what proportion of seats in that coach are reserved. If you don't have a reservation you probably want to aim for a coach with few reservations to maximise your chance of getting a seat.

This is all based on personal experience. I don't know of any official source.

Comment: Regarding a source you can also cross reference with http://ehelp.thetrainline.com/euf/assets/images/seating-plan-virgintrains.pdf